# Write a function (containg bitwise operations) in lua

Tags: c, lua

I have the following alogorithm and I want to implment it in lua. I m locking for how to implement the bitwise operations in lua.

```
void wepkey64(char *passphrase, unsigned char k64[4][5])
{
    unsigned char pseed[4] = {0};
    unsigned int randNumber, tmp;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(passphrase); i++)
    {
        pseed[i%4] ^= (unsigned char) passphrase[i];
    }

    randNumber = pseed[0] | (pseed[1] << 8) | (pseed[2] << 16) | (pseed[3] << 24);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            randNumber = (randNumber * 0x343fd + 0x269ec3) & 0xffffffff;
            tmp = (randNumber >> 16) & 0xff;
            k64[i][j] = (unsigned char) tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the equivalent of this function in lua scipting? especially the bitwise operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recent versions of lua already support this http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.7, but if you are stuck on an older version:

`randNumber = pseed[0] | (pseed[1] << 8) | (pseed[2] << 16) | (pseed[3] << 24);`
is the equivalet of `pseed[0] + (pseed[1] * 256) + (pseed[2] * 65536) + (pseed[3] * 16777216)`

`tmp = (randNumber >> 16) & 0xff;` is the equivalent of `(randnumber / 65536) % 0x100` (that would be the integer div and modulus operations)

`randNumber = (randNumber * 0x343fd + 0x269ec3) & 0xffffffff;` is roughly `(randNumber * 0x343fd + 0x269ec3) % 0x100000000;

XOR (^) can be implemented as A^B=A+B-2(A&B)

Comment: `randnumber = 55555; print((randnumber / 65536) % 0x100)` gives 0.8477 instead of 0

Comment: Yes, XOR can be implemented using `+`, `-` and `&`.  But how will you calculate bitwise AND without bitwise library?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ... I did mention that the / and % were integer div and modulus - you would never get a decimal in integer math... I missed the & in xor, so it would involve a loop function like `xor(x,y){ s = 2; r = 0;
while(s<=x && s<=y){
  r+=(x+y)%s;
  x-=x%s;
  y-=y%s;
  s*=2;
}
return r;
}`

Answer (score 5):

In standard Lua 5.1 there are no bit-operations. There are two solutions two your problem though.

1. You can try and use [BitOp](http://bitop.luajit.org/) from [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/).
2. You can compile your C-function to a shared library, and call it directly from Lua.

I'd go with option 2.

Comment: I'd go with option 1 (LuaJIT is shipped with BitOp included).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [bitlib library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.7) that is part of the Lua standard library since version 5.2. Hex-integer literals work just they way the do in C.

A major gotcha here is that Lua uses double-precision floats for representing numbers, but the operations defined by bitlib are performed on 32 bit integers. As the documentation states, conversions between those two representations sometimes lead to undefined (i.e. implementation-specific) behavior.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, you will have to go with one of jbr's suggestions. Upgrading from 5.1 to 5.2 is not that hard, so if you are free to make this decision, it might be worth to consider an upgrade.

Comment: There is a version of the bitlib library fro Lua 5.1 at http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-01/msg01091.html.